# Timing and length of 'author response phase'

Tags: conference, paper-submission

I've submitted my first scientific paper to [KDD](http://www.kdd.org/kdd2016/calls), an academic conference with a decision deadline of May 12, 2016. However, before decisions there is an "author response phase" (see below). I'm a bit surprised that we haven't heard from the reviewers yet as there is only about 5 weeks from now (Apr 3) to the decisions deadline.

Is this normal? Also, how many days are authors usually given to formulate a response? It seems like we'll have very limited time so I'm slightly concerned with how intense the author response phase will be (seeing as I also have other ongoing projects).

> Papers will be reviewed by members of the KDD program committee and
>   decisions will be emailed to all authors by May 12, 2016. Note that
>   there will be an author response phase between submission and
>   decisions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's still relatively rare for conferences to have an author response period at all, and when it happens, it's typically very different from the response to a journal submission.

For a journal, you are expected to submit a revised version explaining how you've changed things to deal with reviewer criticism. For a conference, on the other hand, the author response period is typically more an opportunity for quality control on reviewers, in which the authors get a chance to say things like: "Reviewer #3 claims that this paper should be rejected because we didn't do experiments, which we find confusing because several key experiments are presented on pages 4-5."  The program chairs then use this review/rebuttal pairing to make decisions on which papers will be accepted and whether they will need shepherding to ensure quality of the camera-ready (for those conferences that use shepherding).

As such, the response time is typically quite short, often only around a week, and typically happens not long before decisions are scheduled to be sent.

Comment: +1 This. Author response phase for CS conferences, is a not a major revision. a) It is for clarifying slight misunderstandings and b) If the reviewers have understood everything (even if they did not like it) for a specific paper there will be no  need for response phase for this particular paper. In this sense, the OP might not get a response phase at all, i.e., it is not obligatory.